# Altering HTML with attributes using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I've been looking for a way to use jQuery to translate HTML. For instance, I would like to change

```
<myTag name1="sally" name2="billy" datingFor="3" />
<myTag name1="jill" name2="tom" datingFor="4" />
```

to another form such as

```
<div>SALLY has been dating BILLY for 3 months</div>
<div>JILL has been dating TOM for 4 months</div>
```

using a jQuery function that executes after the document is ready.

Is there an easy way to do this? I know I can use something like `$('#div').html('New Text')` but this approach doesn't seem applicable when I have parameters (such as the name or datingFor fields).

Comment: [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) docs

Comment: are you getting the `myTag` elements as xml content or as a string?

Comment: to which element you want to append the derived values

Comment: My bad... I think I meant as XML. :( As you can tell, I'm pretty new to this!!! (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3T2ts/)***

```
var myTags = $('myTag');

myTags.each(function(i){
    var name1 = $(this).attr('name1');
    var name2 = $(this).attr('name2');
    var datingFor = $(this).attr('datingFor');
    $('.container').append('<div>' + name1 + ' has been dating '+ name2 + 'for '+ datingFor + ' months</div>');
    //$(this).replaceWith('<div>' + name1 + ' has been dating '+ name2 + 'for '+ datingFor + ' months</div>');
});
```

If you want to replace the existing `myTag` with the generated div.Use `.replaceWith()` instead of `.append()`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! In particular, I like the demo! I'm in the process of integrating your answer into my code and assuming it works I will mark yours as the answer.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks to all the answers. I looked quite a while on the internet trying to figure it out but all of you were able to clearly demonstrate how to do this!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('myTag').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        name1 = $this.attr('name1'),
        name2 = $this.attr('name2'),
        dating = $this.attr('datingFor');

    $this.replaceWith($('<div/>').text(name1 + ' has been dating ' + name2 + ' for ' + dating + ' months'));
});
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/92ctS/ but I had to modify the tags from `<myTag/>` to `<myTag></myTag>` to have it work on Firefox.

This works with original tags though: http://jsfiddle.net/92ctS/1/

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('myTag').replaceWith(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    return '<div>' + $this.attr('name1') + ' has been dating ' + $this.attr('name2') + ' for ' + $this.attr('datingFor') + ' months</div>'
})
```

Update: Since the OP has a string

```
var string = '<myTag name1="sally" name2="billy" datingFor="3" /><myTag name1="jill" name2="tom" datingFor="4" />';

var list = $(string).map(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    return '<div>' + $this.attr('name1') + ' has been dating ' + $this.attr('name2') + ' for ' + $this.attr('datingFor') + ' months</div>'
}).get();

$('body').append(list.join(''))
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/fhzep/)